# Conversation from NSCFString to NSNumber

Tags: iphone, nsstring, type-conversion, nsnumber

**I've below numbers which are stored as NSCFString into SQLite**

---

**These numbers converts perfectly**

475602307163925662

1529228456639250520

**I am converting these like**, `(NSNumber *) [myDictionary valueForKey:@"stringData"];` **and its working perfectly**

---

**These numbers couldn't converts perfectly**

14154269406789154303

13207084142614401684

12870871772958895646

I want to convert these NSCFString into NSNumber. I try using below code and google it but dont get exact solution as I want. Any help would be appriciated.

```
NSNumberFormatter *f=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *myNumber=[f numberFromString:[myDictionary valueForKey:@"stringData"]];
[f release];
```

but it converts my number something like 9.45214212452152

I tried some other way as well but its also not working well.

```
NSNumber *myNumber=[NSNumber numberWithLong:[myDictionary valueForKey:@"stringData"]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting an object as another object (aka `(NSNumber *)`) does **not** "convert" it. It just promises the compiler that you're working with an object of that class **which you aren't**.

The reason why some numbers are totally failing is because they're too large to fit in the standard int/float/long sizes. Instead of `NSNumber`, use `NSDecimalNumber` - a subclass of `NSNumber` (so you can still use all of the `NSNumber` methods as well). It's specifically designed to handle large numbers:

`NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:<your string object>];`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But I want to convert the numbers those I've specified in my question only. As now, `14154269406789154303` this number to NSNumber.

Comment: Jack, is it possible to convert NSDecimalNumber to NSNumber. I know its totally wrong then the answer. But I want it in NSNumber only.

Comment: An NSDecimalNumber *is* an NSNumber. It's a subclass. That means you can use it anywhere you'd use an NSNumber. All we get from the subclass is that handy `decimalNumberWithString:` method that takes really large numbers and converts them into numbers NSNumber can understand.